# Rewriting URIs with parameters using .htaccess

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess

hi i need to know how htaccess file should be modified according to the below scenario.

convert this localhost/site1/viewUser?selectedSearchedUsername=user1

to something like this localhost/site1/viewUser/user1

I currently use below code snippet in htaccess for hide php extension and it works fine.but still no luck in hiding get variables in url as above scenario

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

thanx..

Answer (score 0):

To convert this HTTP request from

```
http://localhost/site1/viewUser?selectedSearchedUsername=user1
```

to

```
http://localhost/site1/viewUser/user1
```

You can simply use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/site1/viewUser/(.*) /site/viewUser?selectedSearchedUsername=$1 [L]
```

The `[L]` is here to indicate that this is the last rule. You might be careful and want to be more restrictive in what you are allowing to match. For example if the username is only a sequence of ascii letters and numbers you can catch that, or you can sanitize letter in your program. Just be careful to not leave the door open.